# Meteor: Unknown package: scss

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting the following when trying to fix the above error:
[image]

Things I've tried/looked at:

- `.meteor/packages` does not contain a package called `scss` at all
- `.meteor/versions` doesn't contain a package called `scss` at all
- No such folder called `packages/scss`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a package that uses scss as its dependency. The package has not been updated to use the new meteor naming convention yet.

It would be one of the packages given by `meteor list`. If you remove this package or update it to a 0.9.0 compatible package you wont have this issue.

Unfortunately meteor doesn't tell us which package is causing it directly.